# Return average deposit,withdrawal for last eight weeks in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to write a simple query that will return me average deposits and bets from MyTable, but for last eight weeks starting from today and to have also in select first day of that week in format dd/mm

```
     SELECT 
             [PlayerId],
             SUM(Aggr.DepositAmount)                                                    [Deposits],
             SUM(Aggr.DepositCount)                                                     [DepositCount],
             SUM(Aggr.WithdrawalAmount)                                                 [Withdrawals],                      
             SUM(Aggr.WithdrawalCount)                                                  [WithdrawalCount]
      FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactPaymentAgr] Aggr
      WHERE (TimeId BETWEEN @CurrentWeek AND @CurrentWeek7)
      GROUP BY [PlayerId]
```

and after that i will just calculate average deposit and withdrawal

so final result i want to be something like

Week,Week_in_format_dd/mm,PlayerId,average_depos,average_withdraw

Comment: So what exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: Simply replace SUM() with AVG()

Comment: See the edited question

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my query to correspond your last requirements

```
DECLARE @first_date DATETIME

SET @first_date = DATEADD(ww, -8, GETDATE())

SELECT T.week_number,
            T.date_formatted,
            T.playerID,
            AVG(DepositAmount) AS avg_deposit,
            AVG(WithdrawalAmount) AS avg_withdrawal
    FROM
        (SELECT 
                DATEPART(ww, timeID) AS week_number,
                SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, timeID, 103), 1, 5) AS date_formatted,
                PlayerID,
                DepositAmount,
                WithdrawalAmount)
        FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactPaymentAgr] Aggr
        WHERE TimeId >= @first_date) AS T
    GROUP BY week_number,
             date_formatted,
             playerID
```

Comment: I am not sure about syntax right now, but the approach is accurate and excellent